# R code to normalize the test set

Tags: r

I would like to normalize the data this way:

```
(trainData - mean(trainData)) / sd(trainData)

(testData - mean(trainData)) / sd(trainData)
```

For the Train set I can use the function scale(). How can I do for the test set? I tried in different ways the `lapply()` function .. but I did not succeed.
Many thanks! An exemple of code:

```
Train <- data.frame(matrix(c(1:100),10,10))
Test <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100),10,10))
scaled.Train <- scale(Train)
ct <- ncol(Test)
rt <- nrow(Test)
ncol(Train)
sdmatrix <- data.frame(matrix(,rt,ct))
for (i in 1:ct){
  sdmatrix[1,i] <- mean(Train[,i])
  sdmatrix[2,i] <- sd(Train[,i])
} 
Test <- rbind(Test, sdmatrix)
normTest <- function(x){
  a <- x[rt-1]
  b <- x[rt]
  x <- (x-a)/b
}
Test <- lapply(Test[1:(rt-2),],normTest)
```

Comment: You need to share a reproducible example.

Comment: Tanks Rana, 
I added the code.

Comment: It looks like the loop structure in last line should be like `lapply(Test[1:(rt-2)],normTest)` because with what you have in your code is an incorrect dimension due to syntax.

Comment: Oh yeah! I wrote badly!